# Make new column in Panda dataframe by adding values from other columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with values like

```
A B
1 4
2 6
3 9
```

I need to add a new column by adding values from column A and B, like

```
A B C
1 4 5
2 6 8
3 9 12
```

I believe this can be done using lambda function, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You can do `df['C'] = df.sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Very simple:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B']
```

Comment: I get the following warning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Running __version__ gives me '0.16.2'

Comment: I get the same warning with version: 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: @spec3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: I'm having issue to display a fourth column.I have  `a,b,c ` columns already. But when I try to make a sum of `b + c = d `I got an `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute c`. What would be the issue?

Comment: @n00b: Try explicitly copying the DataFrame before running assignments on it: `df = df.copy(); df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B']`

Answer (score 84):

Building a little more on Anton's answer,  you can add all the columns like this:

```
df['sum'] = df[list(df.columns)].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I can't believe there are not many upvotes for this answer. This is the only one where you don't need to type column names individually to get the sum! Thanks @sparrow!

Comment: you could drop `list(df.columns)` as it's redundant here. So final code should look like `df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)`

Comment: Fantastic answer. I have a slightly different requisite, that is sum the values for all the columns with a given prefix, resolved by `df[[s for s in df.columns if 'MY_PREFIX' in s]].sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 56):

The simplest way would be to use DeepSpace answer. However, if you really want to use an anonymous function you can use apply:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['A'] + row['B'], axis=1)
```

Comment: any idea how to support variant columns ?

Answer (score 37):

You could use `sum` function to achieve that as @EdChum mentioned in the comment:

```
df['C'] =  df[['A', 'B']].sum(axis=1)

In [245]: df
Out[245]: 
   A  B   C
0  1  4   5
1  2  6   8
2  3  9  12
```

Answer (score 17):

As of Pandas version 0.16.0 you can use `assign` as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,6,9]})
df.assign(C = df.A + df.B)

# Out[383]: 
#    A  B   C
# 0  1  4   5
# 1  2  6   8
# 2  3  9  12
```

You can add multiple columns this way as follows:

```
df.assign(C = df.A + df.B,
          Diff = df.B - df.A,
          Mult = df.A * df.B)
# Out[379]: 
#    A  B   C  Diff  Mult
# 0  1  4   5     3     4
# 1  2  6   8     4    12
# 2  3  9  12     6    27
```

Comment: This method avoids the warning that @n00b spoke of.

Answer (score 17):

You could do:

```
df['C'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

If you only want to do numerical values:

```
df['C'] = df.sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
```

The parameter `axis` takes as arguments either `0` or `1`, with `0` meaning to sum across columns and `1` across rows.

Answer (score 4):

Concerning n00b's comment: "I get the following warning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

I was getting the same error. In my case it was because I was trying to perform the column addition on a dataframe that was created like this:

```
df_b = df[['colA', 'colB', 'colC']]
```

instead of:

```
df_c = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['colA', 'colB', 'colC'])
```

df_b is a copy of a slice from df
df_c is an new dataframe. So

```
df_c['colD'] = df['colA'] + df['colB']+ df['colC']
```

will add the columns and won't raise any warning. Same if .sum(axis=1) is used.

Answer (score 4):

Can do using [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
In [37]:  df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[4,6,9]})

In [38]: df
Out[38]:
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  6
2  3  9

In [39]: df['C']=df.loc[:,['A','B']].sum(axis=1)

In [40]: df
Out[40]:
   A  B   C
0  1  4   5
1  2  6   8
2  3  9  12
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add a comment responding to the error message n00b was getting but I don't have enough reputation. So my comment is an answer in case it helps anyone...

n00b said:

> I get the following warning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

He got this error because whatever manipulations he did to his dataframe prior to creating `df['C']` created a view into the dataframe rather than a copy of it. The error didn't arise form the simple calculation `df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B']` suggested by DeepSpace.

Have a look at the [Returning a view versus a copy](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) docs.

Answer (score 0):

[`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) lets you sum and create columns right away:

```
In [8]: df.eval('C = A + B', inplace=True)

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
   A  B   C
0  1  4   5
1  2  6   8
2  3  9  12
```

Since `inplace=True` you don't need to assign it back to `df`.

Answer (score -2):

You can solve it by adding simply:
df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B']

Comment: why is this answer voted down? Does it not work? Or is the performance to bad? Please give some more hints.