# How to create a variable and store it values for 50 observation(python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i have two variable Total days and total present - so i need to create a new variable called percentage(total present/total days) and store the values in it.....like wise i needed to do for all the 50 values...i tried something like this

```
percentage = 0 
while percentage < 51:
    print(attend['Total present']/attend['Total days'])
    percentage = percentage + 1
```

Can someone help me to understand on how to write a function

This is the data

```
Total days  Total present

90  79
90  69
90  78
90  66
90  83
90  72
90  79
90  65
90  75
90  84
90  80
90  69
90  80
90  83
90  65
90  74
90  75
90  82
90  82
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `Total days` and `Total present`? are they list or dataframe?

Comment: both are Int data types and its a data frame

Comment: and what should be datatype of your expected output? is it pandas column or list?

Comment: [pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns)

Comment: [make-new-column-in-panda-dataframe-by-adding-values-from-other-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023918/make-new-column-in-panda-dataframe-by-adding-values-from-other-columns)

Comment: Questions that show no research effort at all - also no [mcve] are getting downvotet and closed. Please search SO for a solution before you post a question - chances are there are (several) solutions already provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps either in Jupyter Notebook or in Python script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n=0
attend=list()
while n < 51:
    arr = np.random.rand(1)
    attend.append([90,int(arr[0]*100)])
    n= n+1
df = pd.DataFrame(attend, columns=['Total days','Total present'])
df['percentage'] = (df['Total present']/ df['Total days'])*100
```

[image]